# How to combine .txt files from multiple folders

Tags: r

I want to combine multiple `.txt` files in R from multiple folders. However, I'm running into trouble when I want to separate the data into different columns. Right now, the files combine but into one single column when there should be four.

I used `list.files` to find `.txt` files in the folders in my working directory. Then I used `rbind` and `lapply` to combine them with `read.delim`. (see below)

```
files = list.files(pattern = "*.txt")

myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.delim(x, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

The above code combines all of the `.txt` files, but the first 3 rows of each file are artifacts of the data download (basically just a naming feature) and are not pertinent to the data itself. So once the files are combined, the three lines repeat. I cannot use `filter()`, as I would have to manually go through the data (many thousands of lines). I would also like to repeat this process in another folder with a similar setup. So I'd like to be able to use the same code.

I think I can resolve the issue by removing the top 3 lines of each `.txt` file before combining them. Then I can set `header = FALSE` and just add in headers once the files are combined. But again, there are many hundreds of files, so I do not wish to do this manually. I'm not sure how to do this, though. Any suggestions?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `read.delim(..., skip=3)` should skip the first three lines of each file, though it will likely affect your header row, too. That's not huge, though, since you can always re-read one file with `read.delim(..., nrows=3)` (to get just one copy of all three rows) or `read.delim(..., nrows=1)[0,]` to get just the column names. Another option: `read.delim(..., skip = if (x == files[1]) 0 else 3, nrows = if (x == files[1]) 1 else -1))`.

Comment: **Clarification**: that last portion of code is skipping most of the first file. You'll need to re-run the first file. Oops, my bad. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

Options, transcribed from the comment:

- By itself, `read.delim(..., skip = 3)` will remove those leading duplicate rows. This will also remove the header row, so all of your frames will have generic column names, not a big problem.
- To fix that, you can re-read the first row of one of the files (first?) to get the column names, with `read.delim(..., nrows=1)`. If we used `nrows=0`, it reads all, so we need a minimum of 1 to limit the rows read; in the comment I included `[0,]`, but since all you need is the column-names, it doesn't really affect things.

You can do it the first time with something like:

```r
files = list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.delim(x, skip = 3, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
#                                                added this part ^^^^^^^^^
colnames(myfiles) <- colnames(read.delim(files[1], header=TRUE, nrows=1))
```